# Package project as jar into war project (Gradle)

Tags: java, gradle

I have a Gradle project which consists of 3 modules:

- `project-core` (no dependencies)
- `project-web` (depends on `project-core`)
- `project-plugin` (depends on both modules)

I don't want to manually add the plugin to the classpath of `project-web` every time I make a WAR, so I would like to extend the WAR task and create a "warWithPlugin" task, which adds the plugin jar to the libs folder as well.

Obviously I can't add `project-plugin` as a dependency, because I get a circular dependency. What other options do I have to package the plugin jar into the WAR?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can just create a new configuration with `project-plugin` as a dependency then add that configuration to your `WEB-INF/lib` directory.

```
configurations {
    plugin
}

dependencies {
    plugin project(':plugin')
}

war {
    into('WEB-INF/lib') {
        duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
        from configurations.plugin
    }
}
```

Comment: That works for the war, thanks. Is there also a way to put the jar on the classpath when I run the web project via Gretty (https://github.com/akhikhl/gretty)? Maybe to copy the plugin jar in an earlier step?

Comment: You could try `war { classpath configurations.plugin}`.